# java.io exception in ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I have connected my server by gps device. And for reading data I'm using the code

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

that produces the following exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 24312C38
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:783)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:280)
at com.tm4u.ServerSocketExample.main(ServerSocketExample.java:34)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception suggests that the data stream you're getting from the socket is not a valid object stream. Object streams are intended to read Java objects that were serialized by a Java process. If you're reading data from a GPS device, I doubt that's the type of stream the device is sending.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you need to use **DataInputStream** or **BufferedInputStream** with **InputStreamReader** to read data from GPS device.

**ObjectInputStream** is used read Java objects sent by other application through the **ObjectOutputStream**. These are less compatible streams. For example: JVM object serialisation protocol must be the same. I doubt that GPS device manufacturer designed this device to be used in this way.

Comment: Thnanks bt i have all redy used both method bt in case of BufferedInputStream i m using readLine() method than after this code program is not execution